# display unicode character in pdf using jasper 4.0.2

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

how to display unicode character in pdf using jasper 4.0.2. I able to generate the report but characters are mixed up.I's not display order of the letter.My net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding is Identity-H , net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name is Iskoola Pota and I'm using Iskoola Pota font to display the text.

Answer (score 0):

Did your created jar with your font?
in iReport "Tools -> Options -> Fonts -> Install Font"
and then load created jar to jvm

Comment: yes I exported the Iskoola.ttf into jar using ireport.The problem appears only PDF. It display correct order in word,html,txt formate.Is there any property to set in jasper PDF configuration?

Comment: i setup pdf font in default style for all my reports like this: <style name="font4pdf" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans" pdfFontName="DejaVu Sans" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>